# Problem with accessing open databases in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I ran into a problem while using a BigQuery when I want to access databases located in US this error message occurs:

> Access Denied: Table bigquery-publick-data:new_york.citibike_trips: User does not have permission to query table bigquery-publick-data:new_york.citibike_trips, or perhaps it does not exist in location US.

[My query I try to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nhkjm.png)

Any recommendations?

I tried to change processing location to EU (where I'm located) but it didn't help. I also set processing location to US and it didn't work either. When I'm querying dataset created by me, everything works properly.

Comment: Direct link: https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?p=bigquery-public-data&d=new_york_citibike&page=dataset&project=positive-cocoa-306715  You can run queries, or copy tables to your own dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has a typographical error. It should be `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`. This is the output:

[image]